# ¿Cómo puede una función pública de una clase considerar atributos privados como argumentos?

Tags: c++

En una clase `Board`, hago una función de movimientos (`movimientos`) legales que especifica qué movimientos puedo hacer en el tablero. `Moves` es una matriz de dos movimientos que puedo hacer o anular. Lo explico en privado.

Sin embargo, no parece que sea la forma de explicarlo:

```
main2.cpp:126:14: error: ‘moves’ has not been declared
   legalMoves(moves);
              ^
```

El mensaje de error completo es:

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/NestedMonteCarlo/NestedForBinaryTrees$ g++ main2.cpp -o NestedMonteCarlo
main2.cpp:126:14: error: ‘moves’ has not been declared
   legalMoves(moves); // error: ‘moves’ has not been declared : Yes it has !
              ^
main2.cpp:126:19: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘legalMoves’ with no type [-fpermissive]
   legalMoves(moves); // error: ‘moves’ has not been declared : Yes it has !
                   ^
main2.cpp:133:3: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
   vector<*node> moves(2,NULL);
   ^
main2.cpp: In constructor ‘Board::Board(btree, node)’:
main2.cpp:153:9: error: ‘left’ was not declared in this scope
  if(n->*left != NULL)
         ^
main2.cpp:154:3: error: ‘moves’ was not declared in this scope
   moves[0] = n->*left;//DONE? array of the left and right positions from curren
   ^
main2.cpp:155:3: error: ‘moves’ was not declared in this scope
   moves[1] = n->*right;
   ^
main2.cpp:155:18: error: ‘right’ was not declared in this scope
   moves[1] = n->*right;
                  ^
main2.cpp: At global scope:
main2.cpp:160:28: error: ‘int Board::legalMoves’ is not a static data member of ‘class Board’
 int Board::legalMoves(moves){
                            ^
main2.cpp:160:23: error: ‘moves’ was not declared in this scope
 int Board::legalMoves(moves){
                       ^
main2.cpp:160:29: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
 int Board::legalMoves(moves){
                             ^
```

Entonces, ¿cómo puede una función pública de una clase considerar atributos privados como argumentos?

Escribí todo el código en un archivo: main2.cpp:

```
#define NULL 0
#include <vector>

// main2

struct node
{
  int key_value;
  node *left;
  node *right;
};

class btree
{
    public:
        btree();
        ~btree();

        void insert(int key);
        node *search(int key);
        void destroy_tree();

    private:
        void destroy_tree(node *leaf);
        void insert(int key, node *leaf);
        node *search(int key, node *leaf);

        node *root;
};

btree::btree()
{
  root=NULL;
}

btree::~btree()
{
  destroy_tree();
}

void btree::destroy_tree(node *leaf)
{
  if(leaf!=NULL)
  {
    destroy_tree(leaf->left);
    destroy_tree(leaf->right);
    delete leaf;
  }
}

void btree::insert(int key, node *leaf)
{
  if(key< leaf->key_value)
  {
    if(leaf->left!=NULL)
     insert(key, leaf->left);
    else
    {
      leaf->left=new node;
      leaf->left->key_value=key;
      leaf->left->left=NULL;    //Sets the left child of the child node to null
      leaf->left->right=NULL;   //Sets the right child of the child node to null
    }  
  }
  else if(key>=leaf->key_value)
  {
    if(leaf->right!=NULL)
      insert(key, leaf->right);
    else
    {
      leaf->right=new node;
      leaf->right->key_value=key;
      leaf->right->left=NULL;  //Sets the left child of the child node to null
      leaf->right->right=NULL; //Sets the right child of the child node to null
    }
  }
}
void btree::insert(int key)
{
  if(root!=NULL)
    insert(key, root);
  else
  {
    root=new node;
    root->key_value=key;
    root->left=NULL;
    root->right=NULL;
  }
}
node *btree::search(int key, node *leaf)
{
  if(leaf!=NULL)
  {
    if(key==leaf->key_value)
      return leaf;
    if(key<leaf->key_value)
      return search(key, leaf->left);
    else
      return search(key, leaf->right);
  }
  else return NULL;
}

node *btree::search(int key)
{
  return search(key, root);
}

void btree::destroy_tree()
{
  destroy_tree(root);
}

class Board{

    public:
        Board();
        ~Board();

        //a Board is made from a binary tree. Furthermore he has a score, a length
        Board(btree,node);

        //And he has possible blows
        legalMoves(moves); // error: ‘moves’ has not been declared : Yes it has ! Just below !

    private:
        //member variables
        int length;
        int score;
        // create move ? Array of the following possibilities : left/right ? Or none if we reached the end
        vector<*node> moves(2,NULL);


};

Board::Board(){
    length = 0;
    score = 0;

};

Board::~Board(){

};

Board::Board(btree b, node n){
    length = NULL; //TO-DO : number of nodes which have leaves BUT how to count them ?

    score = n.key_value; //DONE? : number on the current node FROM node

    if(n->*left != NULL)
        moves[0] = n->*left;//DONE? array of the left and right positions from current state    //node *left; and node *right;
        moves[1] = n->*right;

};

// gives the number of leaves we can play : either 2 or 0 in the binary-tree case.
int Board::legalMoves(moves){
    //If there is leaves there is at least two moves.
    if(n->*left != NULL){
        return 2;  
    }//otherwise there is no possibilities
    else{
        return 0;
    }

};

/**/

double playout (Board * board) {
  Move listeCoups [MaxLegalMoves];
  while (true) {
    int nb = board->legalMoves (listeCoups);
    if ((nb == 0) || board->terminal ())
      return board->score ();
    int n = rand () % nb;
    board->play (listeCoups [n]);
    if (board->length >= MaxPlayoutLength - 20) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
};

#include <float.h>

double bestScoreNested = -DBL_MAX;

int lengthBestRollout [10];
double scoreBestRollout [10];
Move bestRollout [10] [MaxPlayoutLength];

Board bestBoard;

// What is int n ?
double nested (Board & board, int n) {
  int nbMoves = 0;
  Move moves [MaxLegalMoves];

  lengthBestRollout [n] = -1;
  scoreBestRollout [n] = -DBL_MAX;
  float res;
  while (true) {
    if (board.terminal ())
      return 0.0;
      //return board.score ();
    nbMoves = board.legalMoves (moves);
    for (int i = 0; i < nbMoves; i++) {
      Board b = board;
      b.play (moves [i]);
        //what is n ?
      if (n == 1)
    playout (&b);
      else
    nested (b, n - 1);    
      double score = b.score ();
      if (score > scoreBestRollout [n]) {
    scoreBestRollout [n] = score;
    lengthBestRollout [n] = b.length;
    for (int k = 0; k < b.length; k++)
      bestRollout [n] [k] = b.rollout [k];
    // what is n ?
    if (n > 3) {
      for (int t = 0; t < n - 1; t++)
        fprintf (stderr, "\t");
      fprintf (stderr, "n = %d, progress = %d, score = %f\n", n, board.length, scoreBestRollout [n]);
          int depth = 0;
          b.print (stderr);
      fprintf (stderr, "\n");
    }
    if ((n > 1) && (score > bestScoreNested)) {
      bestScoreNested = score;
      fprintf (stderr, "best score = %f\n", score);
          b.print (stderr);
      fprintf (stderr, "\n");
          bestBoard = b;
        }
      }
    }
    board.play (bestRollout [n] [board.length]);
  }
  return 0.0;
};

/**/

int main(int argc, char *argv []) {
    btree b;
    b.insert(5);
    b.insert(6);
    b.insert(8);
    b.insert(10);
    b.insert(11);
    b.insert(14);
    b.insert(18);

    // create board with b
    board boa(b)

    nestedSimple(b, 3);
    bestBoard.print (stderr);
    fprintf (stderr, "best score %lf\n", bestBoard.score ());

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `legalMoves(moves); // error: ‘moves’ has not been declared : Yes it has ! Just below !` Esta no es la declaración de una función, le falta el tipo devuelto y el tipo del argumento. Deberías comenzar con algún libro que describa los rudimentos del lenguaje antes de aventurarte más lejos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problema.

Te falta el tipo de datos del parámetro, sólo estás pasando el nombre:

```
class Board{

    public:
        Board();
        ~Board();

        Board(btree,node);
        legalMoves(vector<*node> moves);
 //       tipo --> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^^^^^ <-- nombre

    private:
        int length;
        int score;
        vector<*node> moves(2,NULL);
};
```

#### Explicación.

En una declaración o definición de función de C++ los nombres de los parámetros de función son opcionales:

```
int funcion_int(int);
```

La línea anterior declara una función llamada `funcion_int` que devuelve un entero (`int`) y recibe un entero (`int`), en el momento de definir la función también puedo ignorar el nombre del parámetro, pero nunca el tipo:

```
int funcion_int(int) { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << '\n'; return 0; }
void funcion_void()  { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

int main() {
    funcion_int(0); // Muestra 'funcion_int'
    funcion_void(); // Muestra 'funcion_void'
    funcion_int();  // Error de compilacion, requiere un parametro entero
    return 0;
}
```

Dado que el nombre es opcional, pero nunca lo es el tipo, el compilador interpreta que cuando una función está siendo declarada o definida, lo primero que va a encontrar en la lista de parámetros será el nombre de un tipo.

En tu caso `moves` no es el nombre de un tipo, es el nombre de una variable, así que cuando declaras la función `Board::legalMoves(moves);` el compilador dice que el **tipo** `moves` no ha sido declarado. Lo cuál es completamente cierto ya que no existe ningún **tipo** cuyo nombre sea `moves`.

Sin embargo no falla al declarar la función `Board::Board(btree,node)` porque tanto como `btree` como `node` son nombres de tipos.

Comment: De acuerdo, entonces tengo que crear una clase `Moves`

Answer (score 0):

lo que pasa aca es que estas invocando la funcion en la misma declaracion, lo cual realmente no tiene sentido.
Yo te puedo ofrecer dos soluciones:
 La primera es no usar parametros y dejar que la clase use su propiedad privada:

```
class Board{

    public:
        Board();
        ~Board();

        //a Board is made from a binary tree. Furthermore he has a score, a length
        Board(btree,node);

        //And he has possible blows
        int legalMoves(); //aqui faltabate agregar el tipo que devuelve

    private:
        //member variables
        int length;
        int score;
        // create move ? Array of the following possibilities : left/right ? Or none if we reached the end
        vector<*node> moves(2,NULL);


};

int Board::legalMoves(){

    //la propiedad privada moves puede ser accedida aqui sin necesidad de pasarla como parametro

    //If there is leaves there is at least two moves.
    if(n->*left != NULL){
        return 2;  
    }//otherwise there is no possibilities
    else{
        return 0;
    }
};
```

La segunda es utilizar un metodo publico que tome parametros y una sobrecarga que tome por defecto su propiedad privada sin parametros:

```
class Board{

    public:
        Board();
        ~Board();

        //a Board is made from a binary tree. Furthermore he has a score, a length
        Board(btree,node);

        //And he has possible blows
        int legalMoves(vector<*node> *); //La funcion parametrizada
        int legalMoves();                //La sobrecarga

    private:
        //member variables
        int length;
        int score;
        // create move ? Array of the following possibilities : left/right ? Or none if we reached the end
        vector<*node> moves(2,NULL);


};

int Board::legalMoves(){
    legalMoves(&moves);
}

int Board::legalMoves(vector<*node> * parameterMoves){

    //Aqui accederias con el elemento pasado por parametro parameterMoves

    //If there is leaves there is at least two moves.
    if(n->*left != NULL){
        return 2;  
    }//otherwise there is no possibilities
    else{
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Cabe destacar que ese codigo no compila por un monton de razones mas, pero esta respuesta deberia solucionar tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias ! En la medida en que se supone que esta función da los posibles desplazamientos de un nodo determinado, la posición actual, ¿qué me aconsejarías?

Comment: Disculpa pero realmente no se que es lo que intenta modelar este programa, solo vi el error de C y sugerí una manera de solucionarlo. Entiendo que es un arbol binario pero no se cuales son los desplazamientos o que es un movimiento legal.

Comment: "*Lo que pasa aca es que estas invocando la funcion en la misma declaracion*". No está haciendo eso porque eso no es posible hacerlo. Lo que le ha pasado es que está usando un valor como tipo.

Comment: Obviamente que no puede hacerlo, sino no seria un error de compilacion. Si, en el prototipo del metodo tenes que enunciar el tipo para que el compilador pueda saber que valores espera el metodo. 
Lo que intentaba decir con esa frase es que la linea sola es una llamada a funcion, donde deberia haber una declaracion.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda. Creo que voy a crear una clase Move y los movimientos serían una creación de instancias